# WPF DataGrid ScrollIntoView apparently does nothing if the grid is not on-screen

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF **DataGrid** in a **TabItem**. When the grid is populated, I want it to scroll to the bottom, so I call **ScrollIntoView** on the last item after setting the **ItemsSource**. This all works fine when the tab containing the **DataGrid** is selected (the grid is on-screen), but if the grid is not on-screen because some other tab is selected, **ScrollIntoView** does nothing. The only factor which seems to affect whether **ScrollIntoView** does its job is whether or not the grid is actually on-screen at the time of the call. Is this a known behavior?

I've tried calling UpdateLayout and using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to defer the ScrollIntoView. Neither of these measures make any difference.

Is there a non-hacky way to ensure that if the grid is populated while off-screen (as when another tab is selected) it's possible to ensure that I can get the desired scrolling, ready for when the **DataGrid** is brought on-screen (as by selecting its containing tab)? Would I need to do something hacky like detect when the **DataGrid** becomes viewable and perform the **ScrollIntoView** then?

Comment: yes it is default behaviour of wpf that whenever any visual element is in display then and then some operation and methods are executed, in your case as your data grid tab is not selected so it;s not rendered yet so your scrollintoview wont work

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution - exactly what I described in my question as "hacky" but perhaps not so bad. Found that controls have an **IsVisible** property and an **IsVisibleChanged** event. If **IsVisible** is false when I want to perform the **ScrollIntoView**, I set a "ScrollPending" flag in my view class; in my **IsVisibleChanged** event handler, I check if **IsVisible** and my ScrollPending flag are both true, and if so, perform the **ScrollIntoView**. Effectively I am deferring the ScrollIntoView until the grid is actually visible.

Example:

```
public partial class MyView : Control
{
    bool scrollPending;

    public MyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myDataGrid.IsVisibleChanged += myDataGrid_IsVisibleChanged;
        myDataGrid.DataContextChanged += myDataGrid_DataContextChanged;
    }

    void myDataGrid_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (/* The list is not empty */)
        {
            if (!myDataGrid.IsVisible)
            {
                scrollPending = true;
            }
            else
            {
                myDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(/* The last item in the list */);
                scrollPending = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            scrollPending = false;
        }
    }

    void myDataGrid_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (scrollPending && myDataGrid.IsVisible /* && list is not empty */ )
        {
            myDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(/* The last item in the list */);
            scrollPending = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me out.  I thought I was really out of luck there for a bit.